# GFI Tripping at same time every day,

Tags: gfci

I have a GFI Outlet in my kitchen.  It trips faithfully, every morning at 6:05 AM.  I have checked every outlet on the same line and nothing attaches to anything on a timer that may trigger it.  When we set clocks back or ahead, it still trips at 6:05.   Electricians haven’t figured it out.  It is a source of amusement now.  Any ideas what would do this ?

Comment: Time to change that receptacle. Could it be that the power company is switching something at that time every day, and this particular GFCI receptacle is responding inappropriately? You could switch this receptacle with another in the structure, but personally I would just put in a new one.

Comment: Is this on a multi wire branch circuit?  Something on the other branch could be causing the GFCI to trip. In years past handle ties were not required so if an older home I would look at the wire on the breaker and see if that cable has another hot usually on the breaker next to this one 2 hotts and 1 neutral 1 ground. Other than that I would be replacing that GFCI.

Comment: Which loads are hardwired onto the circuit?  Most kitchens have two small appliance circuits. Can you identify which sockets are on which circuit, and once a day move plugged-in loads to the other one? Alternately just unplug it.

Comment: Do you have a smart/digital power meter? Some power companies use PLC technology for meter reading and other things like switching equipment. Older GFCIs can be tripped by RF signals on the line. Try holding an active cell phone by the outlet. Another idea is to get an electrician to put a power quality logger on the line.

Comment: Have you turned the breaker off for, say, an hour and then turned it back on to see if the trip "clock" adjusts?

Comment: Do GFIs do a daily self test? Maybe try turning the breaker on and off at a time other than 6:05am. The GFI might start tripping at the new time.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a problem with the ground. Does it have power? If so its definitely a problem with the ground. How close is your ground rod to bedrock? Since bedrock is non conductive you could be getting an electron feedback, since the power has nowhere to go it just builds on the rod till it is strong enough to arc. #electronproblems #gotstobetheground  #youhitmewithlightning

Comment: Every day at 6:05 a.m.?